# xCode project app load to device from the Command Line

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

Is there a way to load a built app to a test device, from the command line, which doesn't involve applescripts, bots or third party solutions ?

Most suggestions I have seen involve applescripts, bots or third party software like Fruitstrap.

This link in the command line documentation is broken (image shown below). Googling for "Choose a Destination to Run Your App" lead to Apple docs that only describe the process through the GUI.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]